# How to add listener for ExtJS4 chart series inside controller?

Tags: charts, controller, extjs4, listener, webtop

I would like to know how to add `itemmouseup` listener of an chart's series into controller?

My controller's init method is as follows :

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'candidateDistribution > treepanel' : {
            itemclick: this.treeStoreItemClickHandler
        },
        '#candidateDistributionButton' : {
            click: this.candidateDistributionButton_ClickHandler
        },
        'competitorAnalysis #slaWiseEmprDistriGrid series': {
            itemmouseup: this.sLA_ItemMouseUpEventHandler
        }
    });
},
```

In this case, `itemmouseup` event handler of `organizationAnalysis #sLAWiseEmprDistriGrid series` is not working but event handlers for rest of the things are working fine.

I tried to change Component Query to `competitorAnalysis > #slaWiseEmprDistriGrid series` or to `competitorAnalysis > #slaWiseEmprDistriGrid[series]` but its not working.

I had to add this `itemmouseup` event handler into code of chart's series which is working just fine but I think its breaking MVC pattern.

Code for my chart is as follows :

```
xtype: 'chart',
itemId: 'slaWiseEmprDistriGrid',
store: 'SLAWiseCompetitorDistribution',
flex: 2,
animate: true,
legend: {
    position: 'right'
},
insetPadding: 25,
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    field: 'empCount',
    showInLegend: true,
    listeners: {
        'itemmouseup': function(item) {
            var record = item.storeItem;
            var slaWiseEmpListStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('SLAEmployerList');
            slaWiseEmpListStore.proxy.extraParams['paramFirstDimensionValue']= record.get('name');
            serviceLineWiseEmpListStore.load();
        }
    }
}] // end of series configuration
```

So I would like to know why this `itemmouseup` event handler is not working in controller?

Also in future I want to convert this app into web desktop like application, but I am not able to find information/documentation/tutorial on extjs documentation site. Where can I get tutorial/documentation about developing web desktop application?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup this event in controller in 2 steps.

1. Add listener to your chart render event
2. In this listener setup your series events.

Regarding desktop application - I only can suggest looking into this example: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/desktop/desktop.html